# TinyMCE English Internationalization (i18n) in v5

Tags: internationalization, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

When upgrading `TinyMCE` I could notice that in the latest version (which is `5.2.0`) for i18n the `en.js` is missing, which was not the case in version 4 (see [DOWNLOAD](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/language/tinymce4x_languages.zip) - no way add this otherwise). According to [docs v5#localization#language](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language) (US) English is by default but there's no English in the [language pack for v5](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/), does it means that we don't need to include this in the `tinymce/langs` (for self-hosting)? Couldn't find anything about this in the [changelog](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/changelog/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor's default is US English so there is no language pack needed for US English.  If you wish to change any of the default strings for US English you can certainly create a file and change the values as you like.  If you don't want to change the default you don't need the string in your file. For example you could create your own `en_US.js` file with just a few strings:

```
tinymce.addI18n('en_US',{
    "Formats": "Custom Formats Text",
    "Font Sizes": "Custom Font Size Text",
    "Clear formatting": "Custom Clear Formatting Text",
    "Keep Formatting": "Custom Keep",
    "Remove Formatting": "Custom Remove"    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and meaningful reply. Wasn't sure about it, therefore preferred to ask here before moving forward.